# El campo con el atributo 'required' eliminado sigue validando después del submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validación, required

Tengo un formulario para enviar varios campos. Dos de ellos son para cambiar una contraseña.

No es necesario completar estos campos de contraseña antes de enviarlos. Sin embargo, si uno de ellos se rellena, agrego el atributo 'required' a ambos campos cuando se modifica a través de jQuery. Elimino los atributos cuando vacío uno de los campos y el otro ya se encuentra vacío.

En la mayoría de casos funciona, con una excepción que explico en el siguiente caso de uso:

1. Relleno **password**
2. **password2** se encuentra vacío
3. Envío el formulario

En este caso, la validación para **password2** aparece, pero si quiero eliminar todo y enviar de nuevo, no puedo:

4. Borro lo que se encuentra en **password**
5. Envío de nuevo el formulario
6. La validación para **password2** aparece de nuevo. Incluso si el atributo 'required' no aparece en la fuente HTML

¿Por qué me sigue validando ese campo si el 'required' ya está eliminado?

```js
$('#password').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).attr('required', true);
            $( '#password2' ).attr('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password2').val() == ''){
                $(this).removeAttr('required');
                $( '#password2' ).removeAttr('required');
            }           
        }
    });
    $('#password2').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).attr('required', true);
            $('#password').attr('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password').val() == ''){
                $(this).removeAttr('required');
                $('#password').removeAttr('required');
            }           
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="edicionPerfilForm" action="actor/edit.do" method="post">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
            <br>    
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
            <input id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">    
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#password').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).prop('required', true);
            $( '#password2' ).prop('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password2').val() == ''){
                $(this).prop('required', false);
                $( '#password2' ).prop('required', false);
            }           
        }
        
        mostrar_estados_password();
        
    });
    
    $('#password2').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).prop('required', true);
            $('#password').prop('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password').val() == ''){
                $(this).prop('required', false);
                $('#password').prop('required', false);
            }           
        }
        
        mostrar_estados_password();
    });
    
    function mostrar_estados_password() {
      if ($('#password').prop('required') == true) {
          alert('Password está requerido');
        }
        else {
          alert('Password NO está requerido');
        }
        
        if ($('#password2').prop('required') == true) {
          alert('Password2 está requerido');
        }
        else {
          alert('Password2 NO está requerido');
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="edicionPerfilForm" action="actor/edit.do" method="post">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="">
            <br>    
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
            <input id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" type="password" value="">    
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
</form>
```

A partir de **HTML5** se dejó de considerar a algunos **atributos** como tales para empezar a considerarlos como **propiedades**. Como bien te indica el compañero @iMangas deberías dejar de usarlo como **atributo** y empezar a usarlo como **propiedad**. Modificando tu código he puesto unos alerts a modo de escuchadores y he modificado el tratamiento de los **atributos** `required` para tratarlos como **propiedades**.

De esta manera podrás comprobar en que estado está cada uno de los paswords antes de darle al botón de "Enviar".

Añadir que la lógica de programación la tenías bien planteada, tan solo te faltaba manejar bien la propiedad `required`.

Comment: He ejecutado el código y funciona con los alert, pero si elimino la llamada a la función **mostrar_estados_password()** del código me sigue fallando el caso de uso que está dando problemas. Es lo mismo que me pasa con la solución de @iMangas ¿Me pasa solo a mí?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Jquery estás usando?

Comment: Uso jQuery 3.3.1. Vamos si ejecutas tu código sin la función con los alerts deberías poder experimentarlo tú también, por eso lo pregunto

Comment: El problema lo tienes en las funciones **oninvalid** y **onimput** que tienes en cada uno de tus input. Entran en conflicto con la validación por Jquery que estás tratando de hacer. He modificado mi snipped para quitarlas y que veas que funciona correctamente el tratamiento de la propiedad required.

Comment: Cierto, gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema en tu código es que tienes que modificarlo como property, no como attributo:

Marcar como requerido:

```
$( '#password' ).prop('required',true);
```

Desmarcar como requerido:

```
$( '#password' ).prop('required',false);
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de tu código funcionando.
Aunque no veo la necesidad de agregar o quitar la propiedad **required** según el usuario llena los datos, ya que lo hace por su cuenta.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqWXZj

Comment: No resuelve mi problema. De hecho si solo ingresas **password** te hace el submit igualmente, cuando debería saltar la validación de **password2**

Comment: Y si no se rellena ninguno no debería saltar ninguna validación y dejarte hacer el submit, pero los estás poniendo 'required' desde el principio

Comment: Actualizado el ejemplo con un color si los campos tienen la propiedad "required" en true.
Si completas solo el password no te deja enviar
Si completas solo pass2 no te deja enviar
Si completas ambos te deja enviar
Si no completas ninguno te deja enviar
Si completas y borras password te deja enviar

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar cuando se realiza el caso de uso explicado en el post de la pregunta

Comment: Por si no me he explicado bien. El problema no es cuando completas password, borras password y envías. El problema es cuando completas password, envías, borras password y envías de nuevo

Comment: El envío lo estás haciendo con AJAX?

Comment: No, es con el action del formulario. A ver, es algo que se me reproduce también en **codeopen** y ejecutando el código desde aquí también, por eso insisto en el caso de uso que he explicado

Comment: Ok, ahora entendí un poco más tu problemática, tienes que hacer un reset del formulario luego de que se envía (en el submit).

Fijate en el ejemplo que le hice un pequeño cambio.